# Long Text Field on Event

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

Our users would like to be able to populate a long text field (more than 255 characters) when filling out an event record. I know it's not possible with standard functionality, and i'm open to the idea of creating a new object to store the information.

I'm thinking of creating a visualforce page, that would give the illusion of the field being on the event, only for it to then send that data to a new record, and link it back (as i know it can't stay in event. is that something anybody has done? If so what steps should I take?

Comment: You can add custom fields to activities...why do you think you can't add it directly?

Comment: @AdrianLarson it needs to be more than 255 characters, which wasn't specified in my original question, sorry Adrian!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible using OOTB. `Text Area (long)` fields can not be custom fields on Activities (`Tasks` or `Events`)

Replacing the OOTB Event Edit and View page is non-trivial and may cause other issues with other clients like LEX and/or Salesforce 1 Mobile plus being future proof

I'd suggest going back to the users and saying - not available in Salesforce and get them to be more terse (<255 chars). Or, if essential, they can attach a file with longer verbiage

Answer (score -1):

It is possible.

You may add the field to Activity Custom Fields (Setup > Build > Customize > Activities > Activity Custom Fields) and to the Event Page Layout.

Comment: see my answer; I had same thought as you initially but OP wanted text area (long)